# "No matching function for call to X" Error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add a new object to a vector of objects of a class called Vertex, which has a constructor like this:

```
Vertex::Vertex(int x)
{
  index=x;
  next=NULL;
  entry_time=0;
  exit_time=0;
  connections=0;
}
```

However, I think I can't put information directly into the vector,and believe I have to previously create an object of class Vertex, ascribe to it the information I want, and then add it to the vector by using

```
Graph::Graph(bool x, int y)
{
  is_digraph=x;
  order=y;
  is_connected=false;
  for(int i=0; i<order; i++)
  {
    Vertex vt(i+1);
    v.push_back(vt);
  }
}
```

But the error "no matching function for call to 'Vertex::Vertex()'" keeps popping up, as if I sent no integer as argument, even though I'm pretty sure that by declaring the object as "Vertex vt(i+1)" I'm sending an integer as the argument. What is my mistake?

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful here.

Comment: You should use member initialization lists instead of assignments in your constructor. For example, `Vertex::Vertex(int x) : index(x), next(nullptr), entry_time(0), exit_time(0), connections(0) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

A `vector` requires that the type being stored has a default (no arg) constructor. This is necessary so that things like creating a vector with an initial known number of elements works. Your `Vertex` doesn't have a default constructor to it is not suitable to be put in a `vector` "as is".

Comment: Not fully correct, having a default constructor isn't required. `std::vector::emplace_back` exists for that reason. It doesn't require copy constructor, move assignment or anything else either, even though it's preferable if intending to work with `<algorithm>`.